# How to change the color of a pixel using PIL?

Tags: python, image, colors, python-imaging-library, pixel

I was trying to change pixel of an image in python using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167269/changing-pixel-color-python) question. If `mode` is 0, it changes first pixel in top right corner of image to grey(#C8C8C8). But it doesn't change. There is not enough documentation about `draw.point()`. What is the problem with this code?

```
import random
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
mode = 0
image = Image.open("dom.jpg") 
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)  
width = image.size[0]  
height = image.size[1]      
pix = image.load()
string = "kod"
n = 0
if (mode == 0):
    draw.point((0, 0), (200, 200, 200))
if(mode == 1):
    print(pix[0,0][0])
image.save("dom.jpg", "JPEG")
del draw
```

Comment: You are changing the pixel in ```draw```. You should either change the pixel in ```image``` or save ```draw```, like ```draw.save("house.jpg", "JPEG")```

Comment: @Melon **Error:** 'ImageDraw' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: Are u sure `it doesn't change`? I tried u code, and it changed as what expected. U can re-check with adding `for i in range(50):` before line `draw.point((0, 0), (200, 200, 200))` to see more obvious effect.

Comment: Works for me also

Comment: @LauReal When I print it, it prints default color of pixel.

Comment: Huh? `mode` is always zero, you set it at the top - how can it be `1`?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense - but the answer is here I suspect https://stackoverflow.com/a/52640755/2836621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is using `PIL` a must in your case? If not then consider using OpenCV (`cv2`) for altering particular pixels of image.
Code which alter (0,0) pixel to (200,200,200) looks following way in opencv:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('yourimage.jpg')
height = img.shape[0]
width = img.shape[1]
img[0][0] = [200,200,200]
cv2.imwrite('newimage.bmp',img)
```

Note that this code saves image in `.bmp` format - cv2 can also write `.jpg` images, but as jpg is generally lossy format, some small details might be lost. Keep in mind that in `cv2` `[0][0]` is left upper corner and first value is y-coordinate of pixel, while second is x-coordinate, additionally color are three values from `0` to `255` (inclusive) in `BGR` order rather than `RGB`.

For OpenCV tutorials, including installation see [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html).