# Python PIL putpixel() placing different colour to the argument

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

When using `img.putpixel( (0,0) , (0,0,0) )` on a photo and then saving as a separate file. When checking the pixel colour on the saved image, the rgb values weren't matching.

e.g. `img.putpixel( (0,0) , (0,0,0) )` returns the colour `14,0,0`

I also tried replacing the initial pixel to white and then placing the colour on top but that had no effect on achieving the colour that was in the argument.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you maybe save as JPEG? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52640755/2836621

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the automatic change in pixel value in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52640023/why-the-automatic-change-in-pixel-value-in-python)